# Working with the SSOAP package

Tags: r, soap

I'm trying to access a web server using the [SSOAP](http://www.omegahat.org/SSOAP/) package. I'm having a hard time figuring out what to do with the result of a successful `.SOAP()` call.

Here's an example from the [user's guide](http://www.omegahat.org/SSOAP/Docs/overview.pdf):

```
    s1 <- SOAPServer("services.soaplite.com", "interop.cgi")
    test <- .SOAP(s1,
      "echoString", "From R",
      action="urn:soapinterop",
      xmlns=c(namesp1="http://soapinterop.org/"),
      handlers =NULL)
```

This appears to have worked, returning a List of 2 where the header info is in the first list and the contents are in the second:

```
> str(test)
List of 2
 $ header : Named chr [1:8] "Wed, 25 Jun 2014 15:53:31 GMT" "Apache" "SOAP::Lite/Perl/0.55" "534" ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:8] "Date" "Server" "SOAPServer" "Content-Length" ...
 $ content: chr "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:SOAP"| __truncated__
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "SOAPHTTPReply"
```

I need to do something useful with the `content`, i.e. turn it into an R object of some sort. If I followed the users manual correctly, I should be able to use `convertFromSOAP()`. NOTE - the manual references a `fromSOAP()` function that no longer appears to exist, but perusing the package contents revealed `covertFromSOAP()`. This however fails:

```
> convertFromSOAP(test)
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘convertFromSOAP’ for signature ‘"SOAPHTTPReply"’
```

As do all other incarnations of that function that I've tried.

Anyone have thoughts on how to get a usable R object out of the `.SOAP()` command? Or can you suggest alternatives to the `SSOAP` package?

Thanks!
-Chase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That example turns off all the handlers, so you can parse the XML string yourself:

```
xpathApply(xmlParseDoc(test$content),'//return',xmlValue)
```

The SSOAP documentation is difficult.

Comment: Thanks, Dave, for the answer. That worked for the example above, but not for the actual API I'm querying...after some more perusing, I found `getReturnNode()` in `SSOAP` pacakge and was able to process the result with that before feeding to `xmlToDataFrame()` from `XML` package. It's clear I still don't fully grok how SSOAP and XML are supposed to work...any recommendations on other resources to check out for some simple tutorials?

Comment: I'm glad I could help, even though it wasn't much.  I don't have good suggestions.  I was looking for some simple examples and tutorials and all I found were questions like yours.